# $P(X\geq{5})$ in a continuous uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I had an exam in which I think I selected the right answer but in the Quiz is wrong.

It is a multiple choice problem that goes as follow:

"The waiting time until a train passes is a uniform random variable between 0 and 10 minutes. If a passenger has already been waiting for 2 minutes, what is the probability that he will have to wait at least 3 more minutes for the train to pass?"

The options are: 1/2; 2/5 and 5/8.

What I thought is the following. If the passenger has already been waiting 2 minutes and we need to know the probability of the passenger waiting at least 3 more minutes that means that I want to know $P(X\geq{2+3})=P(X\geq{5})$ for a uniform distribution.
Given that the density function for a uniform distribution is given by
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}
$$
in this case it would be
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{10-0}
$$

And given that I want to compute
$$
P(X\geq{5})=\int_5^{10}f(x)dx=\int_5^{10}\frac{1}{10}dx=1/2
$$

That is the answer that I chose, but in the exam the right answer is 5/8.

If someone has some idea why the answer is 5/8 I would be glad to know.

Thanks.

Comment: $\dfrac{(10-2)-3}{10-2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want the possibility the passenger has to wait 3 more minutes *given* they have already waited 2 minutes. That is, we want to find \begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X \ge 5 \mid X \ge 2) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X \ge 5)}{\mathbb P(X \ge 2)} \\
&= \frac{5/10}{8/10} \\
&= \frac 58.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know that two minutes are passed, $a$ isn't $0$ but it is $2$. Given this information, the train can not arrive less than two minutes late.

If you want to see it more formally, it is a conditioned probability, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X\geq5 \, | \, X\geq 2)$. The answer of @kipf gives already the way of computing it

Answer (score 1):

- There are $10-2=8$ minutes left in the interval
- and the train is equally likely to arrive in any of them.
- $3$ of them are no more than $3$ minutes away
- and $8-3=5$ are more than $3$ minutes away.
- So the probability of having to wait more than $3$ more minutes is $\frac{5}{8}$.

You wrote $P(X\geq{5})=\int\limits_5^{10}f(x)dx$ but the question is asking for $P(X\geq{5}\mid X\geq{2})=\frac{\int\limits_5^{10}f(x)\,dx}{\int\limits_2^{10}f(x)\,dx}$

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpreted the question. What you are searching isn't $\Bbb P(X\geq 5)$ but the conditional probability
$$\boxed{\Bbb P(X\geq 2+3 | X\geq 2 )}\label{eq_1}\tag{1}$$

So in order to evaluate correctly this probability we know that
$$\Bbb P(A|B) = \frac{\Bbb P(A\cap B)}{\Bbb P(B)},\ \Bbb P(A^c|B) = 1 - \Bbb P(A|B)\label{eq_2}\tag{2}$$

So with all the ingredients
$$\Bbb P(X\geq 5 | X\geq 2) = 1 - \Bbb P(X\leq 5| X\geq 2)=1 - \frac{\Bbb P(2\leq X\leq 5)}{\Bbb P(X\geq 2)}\label{eq_3}\tag{3} $$

These probabilities are easy to evaluate because the uniform distribution has a probability density function $f(x) = \frac{1}{10}\cdot1_{[0,10]}$, so we have
$$\frac{\Bbb P(2\leq X\leq 5)}{\Bbb P(X\geq 2)} = \frac{\int_2^5\frac{1}{10}\cdot1_{[0,10]}dx}{\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{1}{10}\cdot1_{[0,10]}dx}$$

I'll let you end the calculation ;).

---

Note that in $\eqref{eq_2}$ the case of absolutely continous random variable allow us to keep $\leq$ instead of $<$.

Answer (score 0):

**The below answer provides insight into computing a conditional probability via Bayes' Rule:**

"***If** a passenger has **already been waiting** for $2$ minutes,* what is the probability that he will have to wait at least $3$ more minutes for the train to pass?"

The keyword "if" and phrase "has already been waiting" are clues you need to calculate a conditional probability. In other words, you need to compute the probability of one event under the assumption some other event has already occurred. Specifically, they are asking "What is the probability a passenger will wait at least $3$ more minutes for the train to pass *given he has already waited for $2$ minutes?*"

Before proceeding, consider that if the passenger waits $3$ *additional* minutes after having already waited $2$ minutes, then the passenger will have waited for $2+3=5$ minutes. Hence, the question is asking "What is the probability *a passenger will wait at least $5$ minutes* for the train to pass given he has already waited for $2$ minutes?"

For two events $A$ and $B$, the conditional probability $A$ will occur given $B$ has occurred is given by Bayes' Rule

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)} $$

where $P(A,B)$ is the joint probability that *both* $A$ and $B$ occur.

To solve your problem, let $T$ be a continuous uniform random variable on $(0,10)$ such that $T=t$ if and only if $t$ is the wait time of a passenger. Furthermore, let $A$ be the event in which $T \ge 5$, and let $B$ be the event in which $T \ge 2$. Then, the conditional probability of waiting $5$ or more minutes assuming you have already waited $2$ or more minutes can be determined by substitution with Baye's Rule above

$$ P(T \ge 5|T \ge 2) = \frac{P(T \ge 5,T \ge 2)}{P(T \ge 2)} $$

Note the $P(T \ge 5, T \ge 2) = P(T \ge 5)$ because the only way you can wait both $2$ or more minutes **AND** $5$ or more minutes is if you wait $5$ or more minutes. Hence,

$$ P(T \ge 5|T \ge 2) = \frac{P(T \ge 5)}{P(T \ge 2)} $$

As you know, we can solve the quantities $P(T \ge 5)$ and $P(T \ge 2)$ using the pdf of $T$ as follows

$$ P(T \ge 5|T \ge 2) = \frac{P(T \ge 5)}{P(T \ge 2)} = \frac{\int_5^{10} \frac{1}{10-0} dx}{\int_2^{10} \frac{1}{10-0} dx} = \frac{\frac{1}{10} \int_5^{10} 1 dx}{\frac{1}{10} \int_2^{10} 1 dx} = \frac{[x + C]_5^{10}}{[x + C]_2^{10}} = \frac{10-5}{10-2} = \frac{5}{8} $$

Answer (score 0):

Without any information, the probability that the wait will be a total of 5 minutes or more is $\frac12$. Intuitively, one would expect that if we add the condition that the wait is known to be at least 2 minutes, this ought to increase the probability that the wait will be more than 5 minutes (since all that happens is that we're ruling out a bunch of low-wait-time options). Since you are given options, and only one option applies, this is actually enough.